# Fazer condição dentro do render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou apredendo Ruby e estou com um dúvida de como fazer um `if` dentro do render para exibir o `param` somente se ele existir...

Ex:

```
if params[:field]
  puts 'field'  =>  params[:field],
end
```

Como resolvo isso nesse código?

```
render :json => {
    'request'=>{
        'negotiation'   =>  params[:negotiation],
        'state' =>  params[:state],
        'city'  =>  params[:city],
     },
    'response'=>lista,
}
```

abs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monte antes o hash:

```
res = {
    'request'=>{ },
    'response'=>lista
}
```

Adicione os parâmetros assim:

```
res['request']['negotiation'] = params[:negotiation] if params[:negotiation]

res['request']['state'] = params[:state] if params[:state]
```

E faça o render

```
render json: res
```

Comment: Sabe me dizer, porque eu não consigo popular esse hash antes de instancia-lo?

Comment: Não entendi sua dúvida.

Comment: Porque eu não posso começar adicionando "res['request']['negotiation'] = x". Porque eu preciso criar primeiro o hash vazio?

Comment: Vc pode, nada impede de criar um hash res = {} e ir adicionando as chaves necessárias.

Comment: Isso, mas porque eu devo criar ele zerado primeiro? No PHP por exemplo eu não preciso criar um $array = array(), posso começar diretamente pelo $array['chave'] = valor.

Comment: Vc pode, mas no seu caso como vc quer fazer if pra saber que campos vão ou não existir, nao funcionaria. Mas nada impede de declarar um hash assim: h = { 'chave' : valor }.

Comment: Entendi sua pergunta. Não é possível inicializar como no php, no ruby hashes e arrays tem que ser declarados antes de poder ser utilizados.